# Postgres SQL UPSERT too slow query(Performance Issue)

Tags: sql, postgresql, performance, google-cloud-sql, upsert

I am trying to populate postgres table from another table, nearly about 24 millions records. but query become too slow it taking 9-10 hours. the update operation only update 1-2 row each second. i cant understand why it slow.

### Current benchmark

[image]

- Query = `INSERT INTO .... SELECT FROM .... ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE`
- Source table has `24 Million` records
- Destination Already have `560 Millions` records with `indexes`, `unique keys`, `primary and foreign keys`

#### Query(Sample)

```sql
INSERT INTO destination_tbl(col1, col2 .... , col22, false AS processed, null AS updated_at)
SELECT (col1, col2 .... , col22) FROM source_tbl
WHERE processed=false
ON CONFLICT (unique_cols...)
DO UPDATE
SET col1 = EXCLUDED.col1
        ....
        col22 = EXCLUDED.col22
        processed = false
        updated_at = now()
```

Comment: 24 million in 10 hours is a lot more than 2 each second.

Comment: the query has updated 872 records per second. Not so bad

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if I/O is throttled by Google Cloud SQL somehow

Comment: @Harish Nandoliya, please let me know if below information was helpful.

Comment: @VaidehiJamankar, Finally i figured out it was due to huge dead tuples, I had nearly 2 billions dead tuples.

Answer (score 1):

The query performance results that you have mentioned do seem to be according to the query that you have.It is a simple insert query, which uses `INSERT ... ON CONFLICT` which is one of the ways to UPSERT data.However talking about the performance then it matters a lot if you use `ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING` or if you use an `UPDATE` clause.
Generally when a  `DO NOTHING` clause is running , there won't be any dead tuples that have to be cleaned up whereas if you use an `UPDATE` clause, there will be a dead tuple, and cleaning up these dead tuples may take time which is definitely inclusive in the total query execution time.We know that `INSERT ON CONFLICT` always performs a read to determine the necessary writes, the `UPSERT` statement writes without reading, making it faster. For tables with secondary indexes, there is no performance difference between `UPSERT` and `INSERT ON CONFLICT`.
Try to check on the above factors and see if  batch loads are possible or a query division which would allow a reduction in time of execution and also fillfactor value set should help in time reduction.